# Noise Texture suddenly shows only pixels

Tags: texturing, materials

I don't know what happend but my Noise Texture shows only pixels (see attached picture). Normally it should be a smooth distribution. 
I need help to get this back to normal?

Loading the factory settings and even reinstalling blender didn't work.

[image]

Comment: If you can, share the file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your question and paste the provided link, to check for all settings of that file.

Comment: what is the resolution of that image in pixels?